# Drive realtime api with path

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

In the Google Developer Console, for the authorized javascript origins, I can't enter a path. I'm using the example for collaborative text editing at https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_2_set_up_the_sample, and it works in one window, but I can't open the same instance in another browser because the page is redirected to my main page's index.html, but I am running the html file from a separate page.

What do I do?